# Matching index and returning secondary "element"

Tags: python, python-3.x

a few days ago, some people helped me finish some very basic code to match ingredients with their respective recipes:

```
# all ingredients, represented by numbers: 0= empty selection 1=rice 2=spice 3=vegetable 
allIng = [0,1,2,3]

#Each individual recipe(r)

# Veggie Rice Balls
r1 = (0,1,3)

# Curry Rice
r2 =(0,1,2)

# Herb Sauté
r3 = (0,2,3)

# Vegetable Curry
r4 = (1,2,3)


# all recipes on one list 

allRec = [r1,r2,r3,r4]


#ingredients picked
iP = []
#ingredient count
iC = 1

#User given option to pick up to 3 ingredients
while iC <= 3:
    pitem = int (input ("Pick up to 3 items "))

    if pitem in allIng:
        iP.append(pitem)
        print(iP)
        iC += 1
    else:
        print ("Incorrect entry, please pick again")

#sort list
iP.sort()
iP = tuple(iP)

#compare iP to allRec looking for matches
if iP in allRec:

    match = set ([iP]) & set(allRec)
    print ("Match:",match)
```

My next goal is to assign the recipes their names. For example, instead of it printing "Match: {(1, 2, 3)}", it would say something like "Match: Vegetable Curry" instead.

Another previous poster shared the idea of using the index function so I toyed around with this:

```
a = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)]
b = (0,0)

index = a.index(b)
print(index)

match = a[index]
print(match)

# goal is to have "a" saved as something like:
# a = [((0,0),x),((0,1),y),((1,1),z)] 
# and match of (0,0) returned x
```

Any recommendations on which way would be more efficient and then ideas on how to get that desired print out of Vegetable Curry, Herb Sauté, etc.? As always, thank you for your time. Sorry if the title makes no sense, just started playing with code again for the first time in years about a two weeks ago.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, or tutorial resource.  Your question is too broad for Stack Overflow.  Also see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); most of your code should be consolidated to support the new problem.

Comment: @Prune design questions are on topic here as long as they are clear enough and there are existing "state of the art" answers. Actually, coding is 80% design, so if design questions where OT here there wouldn't be much left to talk about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of recipes and their name in following manner as the recipes are tuples, immutable

```
recipe_names = {(0,1,2): 'Vegetable Curry', (1,2,3): 'Herb Sauté'}
```

and then access through recipe_names[(0,1,2)]. But there can be better solutions for the whole problem. As suggested in the comment, these types of questions are kind of tutorial questions and this is not the right platform to ask